# Difference between quoted path and non-quoted one as command argument in Mac Terminal

Tags: mac, terminal, path

For example, what is the difference between the following two commands:

```
sudo ln -s "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3" /usr/local/bin/python3

sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, there is no difference. Use quotes around a path when it contains spaces:

```
cd "/Applications/My Awesome Program.app/Contents/Resources"
```

Alternatively, you can escape those spaces with a `\` like so:

```
cd /Applications/My\ Awesome\ Program.app/Contents/Resources
```

But whatever you do, **don't** combine escaping with quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The quotes just signify that that's the path. If there are spaces in the path, the quotes make it treat it as one string. If there aren't special characters in the path it doesn't make a difference.